# Command to insert keys in Polkadot Relay Chain and Parachain for Custom Validators in ChainSpec?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, relay-chain, key

I have the keys separate in a file. I don't want to insert keys for polkadot js app for each node running the relay chain. Same for collator for parachain.

What is command to insert keys through CLI?

Answer (score 2):

These commands may help you.

```
./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
      --chain raw-local-chain-spec.json \
      --scheme Ed25519 \
      --suri "chaos dice yard frown drastic lemon airport basket sport sentence spoil beauty" \
      --password-interactive \
      --key-type gran

./target/release/polkadot key insert --base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
  --chain raw-local-chain-spec.json \
  --scheme Sr25519 \
  --suri "chaos dice yard frown drastic lemon airport basket sport sentence spoil beauty" \
  --password-interactive \
  --key-type babe
```

Kindly insert your own secret phase of the keys you want to add.